# Как перевести лямбда-выражение в обычный код?

Tags: java, массивы, java-stream, java-8

Всем привет! Может кто-то научить! Учился удалять элементы из массива, и нашел в коде лямбда-выражение. Как это работает — вроде разобрался, но хотелось бы знать как это выглядит в обычном виде. Если я правильно понял, то в обычном виде это будет работать через if/else. Если не трудно, пропишите эту часть кода  не в лямбда-выражении:

```java
return Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i != delete).toArray();
```

Весь код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] num = {1,2,3,4,5};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
    minusElement(num);
}
public static void minusElement(int[] numbers) {
    int[] sh = new int[numbers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sh[i] = numbers[i];
    }
    int key = 1;
    sh = remove(sh, key);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sh));
}
public static int[] remove(int[] array, int key) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i != key).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Один момент: в этом коде ничего не удаляется. В этом коде создаётся копия массива без некоторых элементов.

Comment: Да. Создаётся копия. Но интересует здесь не сам процесс создания массива без одного символа, а то, как прописать лямбда выражение другим способом. Более понятным для начинающего программиста.

Comment: Создаются _две копии_ массива :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот то же только “для начинающего программиста”

```
public static int[] remove(int[] array, int key) {
     int[] newArr= new int[array.length - 1];
     int j = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         if (array[i] == key) {
             continue;
         }
     newArr[j++] = numbers[i];  
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь мне нагляднее, как это работает! Буду учить!)

Comment: Это очень неточный пример, так как с переводом в массив (терминальной операцией `toArray`) не всё так однозначно -- в своём примере вы знали заранее, что нужно удалить именно 1 элемент, тогда как логика в пайплайне более навороченная.  К тому же в цикле использовано _инвертированное_ условие.

Comment: На данный момент - код для меня отличный! Я разобрался как это работает, и как минимум могу попытаться сам переписать кусок кода в лямбда выражении.